# Excel: Match cell and return related data

Tags: excel, match

In excel, how do i check match for a cell in different column and return the cell value next to it?

```
sheet 1
A     B          C        
1     GRADE3     return "abc, ddd" here   <-checkMatch
2     GRADE4     return "eee" here

sheet 2
GRADE3   abc
GRADE3   abc
GRADE3   ddd
GRADE4   eee
```

checkMAtch,

cell C1, return 2 or "abc, ddd"

cell C2, return 1 or "eee"

Comment: Would like to do the checking in C1 instead.

Answer (score 0):

I am not even sure whether yo are trying to match from sheet1 to sheet 2 or vice versa, but guessing the latter:

Copy sheet 2 and remove duplicates, should leave you with something like ColumnA:B below (say sheet 3):

[image: SO19679840 example]

in C2: `=IF(A1=A2,C1&", "&B2,B2)`
in D2: `=IF(A2<>A3,"*","")`

copy formulae down to suit.

Select all of sheet 3 and Copy, Paste Special, Values over the top.

Filter on ColumnD, select (Blanks) only and delete all visible rows.

You should now have an array to use with, for example, a lookup formula as below:

In sheet1 C1:  `=VLOOKUP(A1,Sheet3!A:C,3,0)`

Copy down to suit.

Comment: Would be great if i could do it in one cell..
For this case i would like to have the formula in sheet1's C1. 
abc, ddd are the return answers i would like to have.